# QInputDialog - confirm with enter-key

Tags: c++, qt, key, keyboard-shortcuts, qdialog

Im trying to use QInputDialog without buttons. It looks just like I want, but I connot confirm input (using it for text input). Is there a possibility to confirm with the enter key, so that `exec()` returns `QInputDialog::Accepted` ? Just like escape key makes the dialog return `QInputDialog::Rejected` ?

Comment: the enter key doesn't works because you don't use buttons. In case when buttons are showed, the «OK» button is set as default, so it receives enter key press event, and buttons signal is connected to QDialogs `accept()` slot. Escape key is handled by dialog itself, therefore it calls `reject()` slot. You need to inherit from `QDialog` and handle enter key press event manually, or connect lineEdit's `returnPressed()` signal to `accept()` slot.

Comment: @Pie_Jesu Thanks! Thats what I feared...inheriting...again

Comment: Just a quick suggestion that may or may not work: can you create the OK button as normal, but simply hide it? See `QWidget::hide()`.

Comment: @Anthony Yes, thought about that too, but dont seem to be able to get hold of the OK button member

Comment: Did it llike @Pie_Jesu suggested, inherited from `QInputDialog` and overwrote `keyPressEvent()` to call the `accept()`on `Qt::Key_Return`

Comment: if button is hidden, it doesn't receives events too ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could installEventFilter() on the QInputDialog, then have the eventFilter() accept() the dialog on a keypressevent(). :)

Comment: I solved it by inheriting, but I wasn't aware of `installEventFilter()`s functionality. Thanks for bringing this up!